# My colleague can't visit our website through her provider after long downtime

Tags: dns, downtime, isp

We did a frontpage update some days ago that caused the site to crash. The site was down for several hours. After troubleshooting, we concluded that we needed to cache more content. It had been run too many queries.

After solving that and rebooting of server, we here in Sweden and Norway were again able to visit the site. But a colleague in Tunisia couldn't. It seems to work from another internet provider but not her own.

What could have happened? And what should we do?

**Edit:** I should add: She is able to visit the site through tunnel at anonymouse.org.

Comment: Were there any DNS changes done in conjunction with this downtime?

Comment: @Stephen Ostermiller I don't think so. The server provider (Rackspace) did some updates on the server and we rebooted the server a several times. But no DNS changes what I know about.

Answer (score 1):

First of all I would try and find out exactly what she means by 'couldn't visit the site'.

It white screened / 404'ed / google reported 'can not connect to domain.com' etc etc

If they are at all technical you could try and get the HTTP headers that should contain a lot more info that can give you clues.

Check your DNS on a free service such as http://who.is/dns/yourdomain.com on the assumption that all is the same and configured correctly.

Also this is quite a nice tool to check on the global status of your dns - https://www.whatsmydns.net/

If so I might hazard a guess its a caching issue - probably off your site.  ISP level or locally on her machine.

I assume she has done the trusty server side refresh plenty of times (ctrl+f5 on a PC).

Also you can purge the local DNS cache on a windows machine run/cmd then from the command line ipconfig/flushdns - that has worked for me before.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. She is a Mac user and in Chrome she got "Oops! Google Chrome could not find www.yourmiddleeast.com Try reloading: www.yourmiddleeast.com" and in FF she first get "Searching for sitename.com..." and then "Server not found". I don't know what to look for at the first dns link you gave but there is green lights there. At the other dns link I got a red cross on Paris, France. Yes she has done all refresh and reboot as possible. Also dns flush. Is it possible the provider blocked our site as cause of the downtime?

Comment: I checked - https://www.whatsmydns.net/#A/yourmiddleeast.com it shows your ip as 162.209.11.30.  Which matches the IP/A record listed with your media temple domain - http://who.is/dns/yourmiddleeast.com.  To me this implies that there aren't any DNS issues and nothing is waiting to propagate etc.  Again indicating that there is caching issue somewhere, DNS or other wise somewhere between your site and her keyboard!  Can you get her to check it on her office pc / home pc / mobile all these will probably use different ISP / DNS's and may well yield different results.  PS it loads fine in the UK.

Comment: *Oops! Google Chrome could not find* indicates a connection error. It can be DNS or general connectivity. It does not matter what other DNS(s) say, it does matter what the users DNS says. Have her do a nslookup, whois, dig, or something to know that DNS is working correctly. Also, watch the bottom left corner of Chrome. It can say resolving..., then connecting... Check to see if it appears to be resolving. Another issue is that any browser/OS will cache the DNS data separately. So even if the DNS appears correct, the browswer can cache it for as long as the TTL for the A record plus some.

Comment: But her friend borrowed her internet and then the friend couldn't visit the site either. But with another internet provider it works. She has also been to an internet cafe and it worked fine there. Great that it works in UK anyway, which is one of the largest visit source.

Comment: It's clearly not just on her own computer. All with the provider Tunisiana has the same problem. The strange thing is that this occurred after the crash.